# ASP.NET MVC Displaying Data in the view from a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a view model `EmployeeViewModel` from two other models `Employee` and `HolidayRequestForm` as I need to use them in the one view. I'm having a problem with my view displaying data from my models.
Here are my models:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public int DisciplineID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int ALCategory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AwardedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TotalHoursThisYear { get; set; }
    public int HoursCarriedForward { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntitlementRemainingThisYear { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set;}

}
```

Holiday Request Form Model:

```
 public partial class HolidayRequestForm
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
    public int HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated { get; set; }
    public int MonthCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DayCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> YearOfHoliday { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Employee View Model:

```
 public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public List<HolidayRequestForm> HolidayRequestForm { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller Action:

```
   public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        Employee employee =  db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => 
 emp.EmployeeID == id);
        List<HolidayRequestForm> holidayRequestForm = 
 db.HolidayRequestForms.Where(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id).ToList();

 EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel()
           {
               Employee = employee,
               HolidayRequestForm = holidayRequestForm,
           };

        return View(employeeViewModel);


    }
```

I am trying to implement this model onto my view but I'm having trouble. Here is the part of the view causing troube:

```
@model LotusWorksHT.Models.EmployeeViewModel

<div style=" position:relative;top:40px; border-radius: 0px; border-color: #F47B20; border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right; padding: 5px; background-size: contain; background-color:white ">
        <h2 align="center">Holiday Requests Record</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>

                <th>
                    Finish Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    HoursTaken
                </th>
                <th>
                    Comments
                </th>
                <th>
                    Year Created
                </th>

                <th>
                    Month Created
                </th>
                <th>
                    Day Created
                </th>
                <th>
                    Year Of Holiday
                </th>
            </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.StartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.FinishDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.HoursTaken)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.Comments)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.YearCreated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.MonthCreated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.DayCreated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HolidayRequestForm.YearOfHoliday)
                </td>
            </tr>

   }
        </table>

        </div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're setting your  holidayRequestForm in your Details function to a List<HolidayRequestForm> , but the HolidayRequestForm  inside the EmployeeViewModel is of type HolidayRequestForm  so not a list. And also , if you want to loop through a list of holidayRequestForms in your view , you will need to loop through Model.HolidayRequestForms as its a list and your model is just based on an Instance of EmployeeViewModel

Comment: @arod " foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'LotusWorksHT.Models.EmployeeViewModel' because 'LotusWorksHT.Models.EmployeeViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: @Alica Sorry, that was old code, let me fix that!

Comment: Did you try changing it to :   @foreach (var item in Model.HolidayRequestForm) as that is the list you want to loop through

Comment: And then changing  model.HolidayRequestForm.StartDate to item.StartDate or model => model.StartDate

Comment: @Alicia It worked!! Thank you so much! if you post an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: No problem, will do. Also you don't even need the employee object in your viewmodel if you are not using it on your view . But perhaps you are using it elsewhere on the view.

Comment: I am, but thanks for the tip regardless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

to

```
@foreach (var item in Model.HolidayRequestForm)
```

As its the HolidayRequestForm List you want to loop through here . And then try changing

`model.HolidayRequestForm.StartDate`

to

```
item.StartDate or model => model.StartDate
```

To get at each property.